# How to solve Unicode problem in flask production e.g. Ieeo?

Tags: python, flask, unicode, cyrillic

I am building flask application with some data in Cyrillic text format. When I serve flask development server in my machine, there is no issue whatsoever sending text in Cyrillic format to the front.
However, after deploying it in actual in-house server, ofc that is different machine than that of mine, of my company, all Cyrillic text turn into sth similar to this 'Oeaaiaaaoa?'.
I have never seen this kind of format during my development on my machine and dont know what to do about it.

I have no code or code snippet or file that has anything to do with encoding or unicode in my project because I have no idea where to put those settings.
Only thing I can provide that may be useful regarding code is I am using jsonify from flask with no additional argument specified for response in every api.
Can someone help?

Comment: Can you share some Cyrillic text, and what it turns into?

Comment: for example, Нийт хүсэлт turns into Ieeo ???yeo

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `string.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')` before passing it to jsonify function